# Ways of referring the notion "in a rich way" to colloquial English

Tags: expressions

I'm not well-off at all and I decided to spend my vacation "in a rich (big) way", i.e. to indulge in throwing cash around, booking costly apartments, hiring private jets, dining at the first-class restaurants and so on.

I'd like to be in the know about the ways of conveying the idea of "in a rich way" in colloquial English or English spoken in different parts of the world.

Comment: Your own word works in this context - you spent your vacation *indulgently*.

Comment: How does someone who is not well-off afford a private jet?

Comment: @Cascabel Eight-seater, two drink limit, no wifi.

Comment: Caskadel, you is rules the rust of Inglese with so very many a heavy hand of nomad... that I ain't gonna be in on the origin of your zeal to the cause of this seemly site. Here common people are trying to improve their English, come to know the particulars of the language, explore the intricacies of English grammar and semantics. Alles gute to you and our beloved Guadeloupe!

Comment: @Lawrence's suggestion of *indulgently* is useful, although it takes context to know it's not a reference to, say, over-eating. A similar option, if we're happy with that risk of ambiguity, is *decadently*.

Comment: My wife's name is Claudia, and I live in Guatemala, thank you. I suggest that you visit our sister-site [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If you are suggesting that I am being rude, well, then I am only applying the guidelines of the site. Once again, if you are a learner I suggest...https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: All people are learners, to a certain extent. It is only a question of what anyone's high-handedness may bring on. But a well-educated man shall refrain from bounding the borders for others to act within.

Answer (score 2):

You are going on a 
***[spending spree](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/spending-spree)*** :

> a brief period of extravagant spending
>
> - Louis went on a spending spree, buying new clothes for all of them.

(Collins Dictionary)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm trying to bring the strain of my saying about "richly spent vacation" round to a kind of humouring myself. And it is very interesting for me to know how people can express it this way in different English speaking lands.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to *indulging yourself*, *living large*, and possibly *going on a (spending) spree*, you're also [*living high on the hog* or *eating high off the hog*](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/high-on-the-hog.html):

> I have to do my shopping in the black market because we can't eat as high off the hog as Roosevelt and Ickes and Joe Davis and all those millionaire friends of the common man.

This idiom is often used negatively, describing the spending habits of others, but in older U.S. literature it's also used to describe [one's own behavior](https://grammarist.com/usage/high-on-the-hog/). For example,

> Of course women always have loved me for my money and as soon as Trixie finds my pot of gold, we are going to be living high on the hog, let me tell you.
>
> I ended up not needing a new car, so I spent my savings living high on the hog for a week.

Comment: Very interesting expression, thank you. And what is the origin of "high on (off) the hog"?

Comment: To me (AmE) the phrase *high on the hog* connotes a lifestyle, not a temporary indulgence. By contrast, [*hog wild*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hog%20wild) suggests a sudden or temporary indulgence.

Comment: How is "hog wild" used in a sentence?

Answer (score 1):

I like the idiom [**live large**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/live%20large):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   *US slang*
>   : to live like a very wealthy and successful person
>   // a star who is *living large*

In your example, you could say:

> I have very little money, but I decided to *live large* for a week anyway.

This implies not only that you you spent a lot of money, but that you spent it in a *lavish* manner as the rich would do.

Comment: Thanks a lot. "Living large" is giving rise to a smile in me.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the last poster...

I decided to [***live it up***](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/live-it-up). From Macmillan's Dictionary:

> to do enjoyable and exciting things that involve spending a lot of
>   money

Comment: Thank you for the helpful and zippy expression.

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to extravagant spending by saying that you **pissed money up the wall** or that you **pissed money away**. For instance, an article on the goofy site Daily Mash has the title "[Man who got surround sound looking for new ways **to piss money up the wall**](https://www.thedailymash.co.uk/news/lifestyle/man-who-got-surround-sound-looking-for-new-ways-to-piss-money-up-the-wall-20180830176831)." The first two paragraphs are rife with expressions in the same sense:

> A MAN who bought an expensive Bose surround sound system for his tiny living room is looking for new ways **to spunk away his income**.
>
> Sales executive Nathan Muir feels he should **fritter more cash** after the top-of-the-range ‘kit’ failed to make any noticeable difference to his quality of life.

The usage is especially appropriate for extravagant spending on restaurants or drinks. Based on sources like the above, the longer expression is more common in the UK. In Merriam-Webster, **[piss away](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/piss%20away)** means

> slang, sometimes vulgar
>
> : to fritter away : squander

and in the Free Dictionary **[piss money up the wall](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pissed+money+up+the+wall)** means

> To waste a lot of money; to spend money frivolously.

The Oxford English Dictionary includes both usages under "[piss, v](https://oed.com/view/Entry/144598#eid30389580)".

Comment: I'm very grateful to you. I have special sentiments towards "spunking away income".

Answer (score 1):

POSH is the answer that popped immediately to mind

**from Collins dictionary**
1. adjective
If you describe something as posh, you mean that it is elegant, fashionable, and expensive.
[informal]
Celebrating a promotion, I took her to a posh hotel for a cocktail.